# Loading latest nodes in Drupal sidebar via Ajax (facebook-like)

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-6

I would like to have a facebook-like dynamic latest nodes loader in Drupal sidebar working in JQuery. Each time new node is created, the users would be able to see it in a list (similar to facebook) without refreshing the page. Any advice, tutorial links, etc. will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How familiar are you with module development?  I will suggest the easier, less instant way.  If you really wanted it to be updated only when a new node was added, it would take much more work.  If someone wants to describe that, they are more than welcome to.

Really all you need to write is a block ([hook_block](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_block/6)) which [inputs some javascript](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6) which:

- Sends an AJAX query to a page your module defines (say /nodes/new)
- Displays the data in the block (via the ajax callback).
- Uses set_timeout javascript call to make the call again every so often.

The page will be defined in a [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6) call with 'type' => MENU_CALLBACK and calling a custom function (my_module_nodes_new).

```
function my_module_nodes_new() {
  $output = '';
  $result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM {node} WHERE status = 1 LIMIT 5 ORDER BY `created` DESC");
  while($nid = db_fetch_object($result) {
    $node = node_load($nid->nid);
    // Theme the information here and add it to $output
  }

  print $output; //IMPORTANT - do not "return" $output or it will be inside your theme
}
```

Hope that helps!